# C : Passing auto variable by reference

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I came across a piece of code which is working fine as of now,but in my opinion its undefined behavior and might introduce a bug in future.

Pseudo code :

```
void OpertateLoad(int load_id)
{
   int value = 0;

   /* code to calculate value */

   SetLoadRequest(load_id,&value);

   /*some processing  not involving value**/

}

void SetLoadRequest(int load_id, int* value)
{
   /**some processing**/
   LoadsArray[load_id] = *value; 
   /**some processing**/ 
}
```

In my understanding C compiler will not guarantee where `Auto` variables will be stored. It could be stack/register(if available and suitable for processing).

I am suspecting that if compiler decides to store `value` onto general purpose register then, `SetLoadRequest` function might refer to wrong data.

Am I getting it right?or I am overthinking it?

I am using `IARARM` compiler for `ARM CORTEX M-4` processor.

----------:EDIT:----------

Answers Summarize that " Compiler will ensure that data is persisted between the calls, no matter where the variable is stored ".

Just want to confirm : Is this behavior also true 'if a function is returning the address of local auto  variable and caller is de-referencing it?'.

If NO then is there anything in C standard which guarantees the behavior in both cases? Or As I stated earlier its undefined behavior?

Comment: What is `auto` variable here? Why do you think that? You are simply thinking wrong. This code is completelly ok. `value` is local variable, no matter where it is placed. If it is in register, then doing `&value` returns address from this register. Not much to think.

Comment: @tilz0R: "address from this register" is meaningless.  You can't have a pointer to a register, but that just means the compiler won't use a register (at that time).

Comment: @tilz0R Registers don't have addresses. If you take the address of a variable, it will simply have to be stored in memory.

Comment: @DavisHerring that's for sure, if compiler will put it to register (unlikely), then it will simply use that register as reference later.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
execution of the current block.)*

Comment: @EOF Thanks, I think I am more clear now, could you please post this as answe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C11 draft standard n1570:

> 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects
>
> > 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end, execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the
> >     object is created each time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an
> >     initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or
> >     compound literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes
> >     indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.

Answer (score 9):

You are overthinking it.  The compiler knows that, if `value` is in a register, that it must be stored to memory before passing a pointer to that memory to `SetLoadRequest`.

More generally, don't think about stack and registers at all.  The language says there's a variable (without saying how it's implemented), and that you can take its address and use that in another function to refer to the variable.  So you can!

The language also says that local variables cease to exist when leaving a block, so this permission does not extend to returning pointers to local variables (which causes undefined behavior if the caller does anything at all with the pointer).

Comment: ,Is it also true if a return address of `value` from function? Will compiler make sure that data at that location will be persisted if I am de-referencing it in caller?

Comment: @Vagish: I edited the question (a year ago) to address this case.

Answer (score 3):

> I am overthinking it?

*Yes*!

The compiler will take care of this. If it stores it in a register, it will know how to handle it (with a memory load).

Comment: Is it also true if a return address of `value` from function? Will compiler make sure that data at that location will be persisted if I am de-referencing it in caller?

Comment: @gsamaras: You mean `return &a`?

Comment: @Vagish not sure what you mean. If I return a reference to `int* foo() { int a = 5; return &a; }`, then this will invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the scope of `value` is the body of `OpertateLoad`. However, `SetLoadRequest` assigns the value pointed to, so the actual value of `value` is copied. No undefined behaviour is involved.